# errors with g++ 5 and 6 when using address sanitizer and additional asan flags for static initialization order

Tags: c++, g++, clang, address-sanitizer

My library [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) is tested with 200+ builds on [travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/onqtam/doctest) - x86/x64 Debug/Release linux/osx and with a wide range of compilers - from gcc 4.4 to 6 and clang 3.4 to 3.8

All my tests are ran through valgrind and the address sanitizer (also UB sanitizer).

I recently discovered that not all features of ASAN are on by default - for example:

- `check_initialization_order=true`
- `detect_stack_use_after_return=true`
- `strict_init_order=true`

so I enabled them and started getting errors for code like the example below.

```
int& getStatic() {
    static int data;
    return data;
}

int reg() { return getStatic() = 0; }

static int dummy = reg();

int main() { return getStatic(); }
```

compiled with `g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010`:

`g++ -fsanitize=address -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 a.cpp`

and ran like this:

`ASAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=0:strict_string_checks=true:detect_odr_violation=2:check_initialization_order=true:detect_stack_use_after_return=true:strict_init_order=true ./a.out`

produces the following error:

```
==23425==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_globals.cc:255 "((dynamic_init_globals)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    #0 0x7f699bd699c1  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0xa09c1)
    #1 0x7f699bd6e973 in __sanitizer::CheckFailed(char const*, int, char const*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0xa5973)
    #2 0x7f699bcf2f5c in __asan_before_dynamic_init (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x29f5c)
    #3 0x40075d in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 /home/onqtam/a.cpp:10
    #4 0x40075d in _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z9getStaticv /home/onqtam/a.cpp:10
    #5 0x40090c in __libc_csu_init (/home/onqtam/a.out+0x40090c)
    #6 0x7f699b91fa4e in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a4e)
    #7 0x4007b8 in _start (/home/onqtam/a.out+0x4007b8)
```

The same is with `g++-6 (Ubuntu 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~12.04.1) 6.1.1 20160511`

The error disappears when I do one of these 3 things:

- use clang++ (any version) instead of g++
- remove the `-O2` and use `-O0`
- remove the `static` in front of `dummy`

Why is this happening? If it is a bug - is it reported? How to avoid it?

**EDIT:**

@vadikrobot said that even this: `static int data = 0; static int dummy = data; int main() { }` produces the problem.

**EDIT:**

the answer of @ead is correct, however I found a way to circumvent the removal of the static dummy and asan doesn't assert anymore:

```
int& getStatic() {
    static int data = 0;
    return data;
}

int __attribute__((noinline)) reg(int* dummy_ptr) { *dummy_ptr = 5; return getStatic() = 0; }

static int __attribute__((unused)) dummy = reg(&dummy);

int main(int argc, char** argv) { return getStatic(); }
```

Comment: Good question, but it's missing a small self-contained compilable example to really figure it out.

Comment: @rubenvb ok I'll try to come up with one and will link to it at the end of the question.

Comment: It would be fine if it requires your project, but it would be even more helpful (to you and us) if you could reduce it to a bare minimum of code.

Comment: @rubenvb I edited the question - providing a minimal example.

Comment: @onqtam It seems, that you can simplify your example code by delete "return getStatic(); "

Comment: @onqtam Your example can be simplified to next "static int data = 0;
static int dummy = data; int main() { }" . And this code will still get same error. It seems that it is gcc bug

Comment: @onqtam I have account in gcc bugzilla. If you want I can report this bug.

Comment: I try to see assembler code here https://gcc.godbolt.org. And it is identical in g++ and clang. That's why this is gcc bug, and seems that it is not report. Full link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-O3',source:'int%26+getStatic()+%7B%0A++++static+int+data%3B%0A++++return+data%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+reg()+%7B+return+getStatic()+%3D+0%3B+%7D%0A%0Astatic+int+dummy+%3D+reg()%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B+return+getStatic()%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the usage of asan by gcc. I don't know enough to say that this is a bug (because all I know comes from reverse engineering), but there is at least some room for improvement for gcc. But also asan could be more robust in its handling of this case.

What goes wrong? For my explanation I would like to take a look at the assembler code of vadikrobot's example and later move to your problem:

```
static int data = 0; 
static int dummy = data; 
int main() { }
```

First we compile without optimization: `g++ -O0 -S` [(here the whole assembler code)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1255c4afebd86b20)

The most important points are:

-There are two globals, for `data` and `dummy` integer static variables:

```
.local  _ZL4data
.comm   _ZL4data,4,4
.local  _ZL5dummy
.comm   _ZL5dummy,4,4
```

-In the section `.init_array` are noted all functions which are called prior to `main`. In our case this is `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main`:

```
.section    .init_array,"aw"
.align 8
.quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
```

-As expected, the global variables are initialized somewhere in `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main`:

```
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
    ...
    #in this function is the initialization
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    ...
```

After establishing that, let's take a look at the [optimized version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/750ddd894a15ad1e):

1. The `static` variables are local and can only be accessed from this translation unit, they are not used here, so they are not used at all  and thus are optimized.
2. There is nothing in the section `.init_array`, because there is nothing to initialize.
3. strangely, there is still an unused `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main` function, which does just  nothing. I guess it should be optimized away as well.

Now let's take a look at unoptimized version with `-fsanitize=address` (full assembler code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2d0b769d9c33c62)):

The most important thing: section `.init_array` has now more functions which are needed for initialization of the sanitizer, in the end it all results in  these important functions being called in this order:

```
call    __asan_init
call    __asan_register_globals
call    __asan_before_dynamic_init
call    __asan_report_store4
call    __asan_after_dynamic_init
```

What is different for [optimized version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d299972db392f8fc)?

-There are no globals (they are optimized away after all), so `__asan_register_globals` is not called. This is Ok.

-But strangely the section `.init_array` contains now again the not needed method `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main` which does not initialize any globals (they are optimized away), but calls `__asan_before_dynamic_init`:

```
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    __asan_before_dynamic_init
    ...
```

The problem with this: It seems as if it were not allowed to call `__asan_before_dynamic_init` without a prior call to `__asan_register_globals` because some pointer seems to be `NULL` - your error trace is a failed assertion.

---

After having established that, let's go to you problem:

1. `static int dummy = reg();` is not used anywhere in this translation unit and thus is optimized away, there are no globals and you will run in the bad case of `__asan_before_dynamic_init` without `__asan_register_globals`.
2. without `static`, the variable `dummy` could be used from a different translation unit and thus cannot be optimized away - there are globals and thus  `__asan_register_globals` is called.
3. why does gcc version prior to 5.0 work? Sadly, they would not optimize unused global `static` variables away.

---

What to do?

1. You should report this problem to gcc.
2. As a work around, I would do the optimization by hand.

For example:

```
int& getStatic() {
    static int data=0;
    return data;
}
```

and remove the static variable `dummy` and maybe also the function `reg()`, if it is not used for other purposes.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part - the 'doing the optimization by hand' - the static int data gets initialized to 0 as opposed to my code? I tried it and the error is still there

Comment: Also this is very weird because in this contrived example - yes the statics get optimized away - but I don't think they get optimized away when I'm using my library - because there the ```reg()``` call has side effects and it is not skipped (or maybe the call to ```reg()``` isn't skipped but the static int that gets initialized by it gets removed...).

Comment: @onqtam you should also remove `dummy` (did you do it? See my edit).

Comment: @onqtam the call to `reg()` is not skipped, but its result is not stored in the `dummy` variable, because its values is never accessed.

Comment: oh - removing the dummy is 'the optimization'... well I kinda need it - the whole point is to have ```reg()``` called before ```main()```

Comment: thanks for the answer - you get the bounty - and also see my last edit of my question - I found a way to silence it :)

Answer (score 1):

This should have been fixed in GCC recently: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=77396

Comment: cool - thanks! I tried a few times to report it myself but I couldn't create an account in their bugzilla - it rejected my email or something o_O

Comment: AFAIR they had problems with spammers. You can also report to [ASan issue tracker (though they are likely to reject if bug is GCC-specific).